# mpirun running job serially with only one core

Tags: mpi, mpich

I have installed mpich4.1 in ubuntu machine using GNU compiler. In the beginning I ran one job successfully using `mpirun` on '36' cores, but now when I'm trying to run same job it's running serially using only one core. Now the command output of `mpirun -np 36 ./wrf.exe` is

```
 starting wrf task            0  of            1
 starting wrf task            0  of            1
 starting wrf task            0  of            1
 starting wrf task            0  of            1
 starting wrf task            0  of            1
 starting wrf task            0  of            1
```

The `mpivars` gives error with

```
Abort(470406415): Fatal error in internal_Init_thread: Other MPI error, error stack:
internal_Init_thread(67): MPI_Init_thread(argc=0x7fff8044f34c, argv=0x7fff8044f340, required=0, provided=0x7fff8044f350) failed
MPII_Init_thread(222)...:  gpu_init failed
```

But the machine is not having GPU.
The mpi version command gives

```
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 4.1
    Release Date:                            Fri Jan 27 13:54:44 CST 2023
    CC:                              gcc      
    Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/home/MODULES' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'CC=gcc' 'CFLAGS= -O2' 'LDFLAGS=' 'LIBS=' 'CPPFLAGS= -DNETMOD_INLINE=__netmod_inline_ofi__ -I/home/MODULES/mpich-4.1/src/mpl/include -I/home/MODULES/mpich-4.1/modules/json-c -D_REENTRANT -I/home/MODULES/mpich-4.1/src/mpi/romio/include -I/home/MODULES/mpich-4.1/src/pmi/include -I/home/MODULES/mpich-4.1/modules/yaksa/src/frontend/include -I/home/MODULES/mpich-4.1/modules/libfabric/include'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            hwloc
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Demux engines available:                 poll select
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that typically occurs when you are mixing MPI vendors and/or versions. look at the `libmpi.so` used by `wrf.exe` with `ldd wrf.exe`, then `type -p mpirun` and make sure both are related to the same vendor and version.

Comment: ```libmpi.so``` is directing to ```libmpi.so -> libmpi.so.12.2.4``` whereas in ```ldd wrf.exe``` pointing it to ```libmpi.so.40 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40```. when I added this path to ```$LD_LIBRARY_PATH``` and ran ```mpirun -np 36 .wrf.exe``` it gave the error ```[mpiexec@NM] match_arg (lib/utils/args.c:166): unrecognized argument x
[mpiexec@NM] HYDU_parse_array (lib/utils/args.c:181): argument matching returned error
[mpiexec@NM] parse_args (mpiexec/get_parameters.c:315): error parsing input array
...```

Comment: wrf.exe is linked with Open MPI but you use mpirun from MPICH. Either rebuild with MPICH or use mpirun from Open MPI.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I rebuilt WRF with MPICH but error still persist. ```Abort(671732751): Fatal error in internal_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
internal_Init(66)....: MPI_Init(argc=(nil), argv=(nil)) failed
MPII_Init_thread(222):  gpu_init failed``` Now ```libmpi.so``` used by ```wrf.exe``` is directing to ```libmpi.so.12 => /home/MODULES/lib/libmpi.so.12``` and ```type -p mpirun``` directing to ```/home/MODULES/bin/mpirun```. I have multiple versions of mpi. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ```apt-cache search MPI | grep -w MPI| awk '{print $1}' | xargs dpkg -l 2>/dev/null``` showing```ii  intel-oneapi-mpi-2021.8.0    2021.8.0-25329 amd64        Intel® MPI Library ii  intel-oneapi-mpi-devel       2021.8.0-25329 amd64        Intel® MPI Library
ii  intel-oneapi-mpi-devel-2021.8.0 2021.8.0-25329 amd64        Intel® MPI Library
ii  mpi-default-bin         1.13           amd64        Standard MPI 
ii  mpich                        3.3.2-2build1  amd64        Implementation of the MPI Message 
ii  python3-mpi4py        3.0.3-4build2  amd64        bindings of the Message Passing```

Comment: `gpu_init` is suspicious. Do you plan to use GPU on the compute nodes? if not, it might be easier to simply rebuild MPICH without GPU support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251859/discussion-between-ajay-and-gilles-gouaillardet).